# how to limit access to go to url?

Tags: php, laravel

***This is the code of my Middleware.php***

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\User_roles;
use App\User;
use Route;
class OwnerMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $current = $user->find(Auth::user()->id)->role;
        $current = $current->find($current->id)->roles;
            if($current->name != 'admin' && $current->name != 'oper')
            {
                return redirect('/');

            }

            return $next($request);

    }

}
```

***And this is the code of web.php***

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
       Route::group(['middleware'=>'role'],function (){
           Route::resource('users','UseCon');

       });

       Route::group(['middleware'=>'role:client'],function (){

       });

        Route::group(['middleware'=>'role:oper'],function (){
           Route::get('operall', 'ApplicController@index');
        Route::get('operall/drivers', 'DriversController@index')->name('driver_page');
    });

});
```

My Question is :**how can I prevent url (/ users) from going to the user whose role is:oper ?**

> **NOTE:** *role (oper) should not go to those urls that roles are available
>   (admin)*

Answer (score 0):

For protecting your user routes, you can create a User middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware User
```

In `App\Http\Middleware\User.php` you can do something like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if user has permission to access route
        if(!Auth::user()->role === 'user' ) {

            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Register middleware in the kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
     ...
     'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\User::class
];
```

Then protect user routes with created user middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> 'user'],function (){
           Route::resource('users','UseCon');

});
```

Repeat same steps for 'admin' and 'oper' routes.

Comment: Does it help you?